# Find end point of path for all nodes along that path in R

Tags: r, recursion, data-structures, tidyverse, graph-theory

I've got a dataset that encodes transitions between units like this, where Unit A is a unit that supersedes Unit B on a particular date. After Unit A supersedes Unit B, it is now the active unit.

```
Unit A | Transition Date | Unit B
---------------------------------
xxx04  | 1/1/2020        | xxx03
xxx03  | 15/7/2019       | xxx02
xxx02  | 12/6/2005       | xxx01
aaa02  | 19/6/2015       | aaa01
bbb03  | 23/5/2010       | bbb02
bbb02  | 1/4/2009        | bbb01
```

The actual data set has around 30,000 transitions that vary between 1 transition and 30.

What I want to know is for each unit in the data set (both units A and B), if it's part of a chain of units, what is the final unit in the chain. So I would imagine the final data set should look like:

```
Unit  | Final Unit
------------------
xxx01 | xxx04
xxx02 | xxx04
xxx03 | xxx04
xxx04 | xxx04
aaa01 | aaa02
aaa02 | aaa02
bbb01 | bbb03
bbb02 | bbb03
bbb03 | bbb03
```

Based on my googling, I think that this is a graph problem where I need to encode the path between the nodes and find the final node on the path. But I'm not sure how to actually write the code in R to do it. I think it will involve a recursive function that loops over the items.

I would ideally like the answer in base R/tidyverse rather than using some graph library such as igraph so that I can actually understand what is going on mechanically.

Comment: Can a transition be an edge in multiple paths or is it only part of a single path?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proposal that might work:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(unit_a = c("x4", "x3", "x2", "a2", "b3", "b2"), 
             unit_b = c("x3", "x2", "x1", "a1", "b2", "b1"))


# get all units and identify non final units:
all_units <- unique(c(df$unit_a, df$unit_b))
non_final_units <- all_units[all_units %in% df$unit_b] ## assumption: none of the final units appear in df$unit_b

# initial result mapping
mapping <- tibble(unit = all_units, final_unit = all_units)

#get the indices of non-final units in mapping$final_units, i.e. those which need replacement
repl <- which(mapping$final_unit %in% non_final_units)

while (length(repl) > 0) # as long as there are still non-final elements in mapping$final_unit
{ 
    # build vector with elements to be replaced:
    repl_v <- sapply(repl, function(x) df$unit_a[df$unit_b == mapping$final_unit[x]])

    # replace non-final elements
    mapping$final_unit[repl] <- repl_v

    # get the indices of still non-final units:
    repl <- which(mapping$final_unit %in% non_final_units)
}
```